# Image caching in asp.net application without IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, image-caching

I have an application written in asp.net c# and hosted on IIS6. There are an 'Image' folder with 3-subfolders. These folders contained images of type 'jpg','gif','png' etc. Images are very huge in size and in numbers. On the application every page has some images needs  to open/show, due to the size of images my application get slower and slower.

I know there are some techniques to Cache image folders at client machine or some other methods. I have no access on IIS. So, I need some httphandler or httpmodules which provide something like Image-caching.

I tried this : codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx
The problem is I have to add an extra extension '.ashx' to every image link. There is no problem with images are loading dynamically but it has trouble with images need to embose a manual link. Also, this is working fine upto around 1000s images.

All suggestions/solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks everyone - my problem is solved now with this : codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx. The actually working application is : http://singhshashtar.com/

Comment: Cool. Hope this works out for you.

How about a few upvotes for @Oded, @5arx for stopping by to help ;-)

Comment: @5arx - Cool man, I already did it. Thanks once again to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Caching on the client happens automatically.

Are you talking about keeping file in server memory ([IIS file cache](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0483502-c6da-486a-917a-586c463b7ed6.mspx?mfr=true))?

Comment: @Oded - you are right but it took huge time to uplaod images everytime.I am looking something like this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Oded - Thanks, I tried the same but after around 1000s images it get me back into the same situation where I am?

Comment: @Rick - Are you displaying 1000 images on one page? Is that where the slowdown is?

Comment: @Oded- Actually this is an example, images are more than 1000s, needs to show on a single page.

Comment: @Rick - caching won't help you. Is the slowdown happening on the browser? If so, the problem is probably with displaying so many images. Are you putting them in tables?

Comment: @Oded - Images are displaying in DataGrid. Actually we are showing 10-10 images on a page through Datagrid and all images are loaded at once while user navigate the application.

Comment: @Rick - Do you need the DataGrid - its pretty heavy for just displaying things ...?

Comment: @Rick - I am still not clear on _where_ you are seeing the slowdown. Server side? DB? Browser? All of them?

Comment: @Oded-Whenever page [contained images] is loading it slow down the site. Images are in Folders so no interference of DB is here

Comment: @Rick - How are you putting the images on the datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at some kind of buffering mechanism using AJaX. No one is going to want to look at 1000+ images *at the same time*.

Maybe you could take a look at the latest version of Google's Image Search for 'inspiration'  ;-)

Comment: We are using UpdateProgress of Ajax, but the same issue its taking too lengthy time to uplaod images. We are showing 10-10 images in a Datagrid and there are around 100 pages on Grid for 1000s images

Comment: @Rick - do you need to show the full-size imgs as previews? Maybe you could write a custom handler to serve images and resize them on the fly?

Comment: Yes, I need to do it as you said. I added some more description into my query please look into it,